# addItem unit test in php

Tags: php, unit-testing, oop

I am trying to test if an item can be added to my shopping list. I am unsure of where I am going wrong and the error I am getting is:

```
ArgumentCountError : Too few arguments to function Tests\Unit\Entities\ShoppingListTest::testAddItem(), 0 passed in
```

Which is confusing me because I have passed arguments where they are needed? I am new to unit testing and just need some guidance. I also realise that I may of picked the wrong assert to be called so any input on that would be helpful!
Here is my test:

```
 public function testAddItem(string $name): void
    {
        //Arrange: Given an item to add to the shopping list
        $items = [new ShoppingItem('lettuce')];
        $list = new ShoppingList('my-groceries', $items);

        //Act: Add the item to the list
         $list->addItem($name);

        //Assert: Check to see if the item was added to the list
        $this->assertContains($items, $list, 'Does not contain lettuce.');

    }
```

And here is my shopping list class that contains the function I am testing:

```
class ShoppingList implements \iterable
{
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private string $name;
    /**
     * @var ShoppingItem[]
     */
    private array $items;

    public function __construct(string $name, array $items)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
        foreach($items as $item) {
            if(!$item instanceof ShoppingItem) {
                throw new \InvalidArgumentException("Expecting only shopping items.");
            }
        }
        $this->items = $items;
    }

    public function getName(): string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function getItems(): array
    {
        return $this->items;
    }

    public function addItem(string $name): void
    {
        $item = new ShoppingItem($name);
        $this->items[] = $item;
    }

    public function checkOffItem(string $name): void
    {
        $item = $this->findItemByName($name);
        if($item) {
            $item->checkOffItem();
            return;
        }
        throw new \LogicException("There is no item on this list called $name.");
    }

    private function findItemByName(string $name): ?ShoppingItem
    {
        foreach($this->items as $item) {
            if($item->getName() === $name) {
                return $item;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: You must not insert any argument to test function. (testAddItem())

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the passed test. I didn't add another item to the list.

```
 public function testAddItem(): void
    {
        //Arrange: Given an item to add to the shopping list
        $items = [new ShoppingItem('lettuce')];
        $list = new ShoppingList('my-groceries', $items);

        //Act: Add the item to the list
        $actual = $list->getItems();
        $list->addItem('cabbage');

        //Assert: Check to see if the item was added to the list
        $this->assertEquals($items, $actual);

    }
```